# C# ASP .Net, triggering button control inside Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a question about button inside the gridview. As the title says, I designed a gridview with a button inside. Whenever I trigger the button, it always binding the gridview before it can reach the button event.

Say, `onLoad` page, I pull data and bind them to a gridview, then I would like to do a mass update which will be triggered by the button inside it. If i put `!IsPostBack`, it never triggers the button event, which means it always has to read the data bind them into gridview again then execute the button event.

**Problem is**, I have a huge data and it takes much time to update because of it. I am wondering if there are any ways to **trigger the button** event **without rebinding** the gridview again? Is it because of the button inside the gridview so it is necessary to rebind again before it could read the button event?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the RowCommand instead of the onclick event?
you can add a command name property to the button to understand what operation you need to do

Have a look at the link below and just replace the ButtonField with a classic button. don't forget to assign a CommandName

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.aspx

Comment: Tthe button is inside a headertemplate, which allow me to choose button only, not buttonfield.

Comment: you can use the "classic" button as well just make sure to assign a CommandName and create an Handlerd for the GridView_RowCommnad

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the button event, but the GridView.RowCommand event instead. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx). If you do this in combination with the `if (!IsPostBack)` check in Page_Load, it should work for your scenario.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, but it still doesn't work. if (!IsPostBack) doesn't trigger the RowCommand which leads no where, therefore the button inside is also not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

your button must be triggered by `OnRowCommand` event and `! IsPostBack` shouldn't prevent triggering your button

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(object source, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="Update")
    {
    // put your update code here
    }
}
```

and you can use ajax to update your datasource without rebinding your GridView and update your UI using javascript.

Comment: if (!IsPostBack) doesn't trigger the RowCommand which leads no where, therefore the button inside is also not triggered. The gridview binding is inside if (!IsPostBack) i suppose